# Gradle selenium(any) dependencies are not downloading

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, gradle, build.gradle

After creating new java gradle project added following dependencies in build file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjIDh.png)

```
dependencies {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
    implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: '5.3.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng
    testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.6.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.2.2'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
}
```

## Then following popup appeared on vs code.

"Do you want to synchronize the Java classpath/configuration" once and for all? with yes/always/never option

I tried selecting each option in new project. Still after doing gradle build none of dependency downloaded

*So if I am writing WebDriver or WebDriverManager I am not getting import option in quick fix*

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Hi toyota Supra, have updated error in desciption. i.e, after adding dependencies those dependencies are not installed or downloaded resulting not getting import option for WebDriver or WebDriverManager